# deploying spark on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, spark-streaming

i have an error when i deployed my TwitterStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on EC2 
i used this :

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --class streaming.java.TwitterStreaming --master spark://xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:6066 --deploy-mode cluster application-jar TwitterStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

the response was :

```
    {
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20150402200153-0000",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.3.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20150402200153-0000",
  "success" : true
}
```

on browser i'm getting an error below :

```
driver-20150402210100-0001  streaming.java.TwitterStreaming     ERROR   1   512.0 MB    stdout stderr   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/application-jar does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

the `application-jar` in your submit command seems to be extra

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --class streaming.java.TwitterStreaming --master spark://xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:6066 --deploy-mode cluster  TwitterStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Make sure to provide full path to TwitterStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: always error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/TwitterStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist.